# Why do treeview widget put an extra column although I only gave it two? I also can't control the width of it

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, treeview, tk-toolkit

1. I can't figure out how to control the width of the widget
2. I can't make it display only 2 columns

   ```
   from Tkinter import *
   from ttk import Treeview
   root = Tk()
   tree = Treeview(root, height = 10, columns = 2)
   tree['columns'] = ('one','two')
   tree.column('one', width = 50)
   tree.column('two', width = 50)
   tree.heading('one', text = 'UserName', anchor = 'center')
   tree.heading('two', text = 'ID', anchor = 'centeenter code herer')
   tree.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
   root.mainloop()
   ```

Comment: Your code has some extra characters (`'centeenter code herer'`)

Comment: I apologize but I can't see it, where is it exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That first column is the tree. You can turn it off by using the `show` attribute. The value must be a list with zero or more values. The valid values are `headings` to show the column headings, and `tree` to show the tree. The default value is `['tree', 'headings']`.

Here's how to have the treeview show the column headings but not the tree:

```
tree = Treeview(root, height=10, columns=2, show=["headings"])
```

If you want to see the tree, but you want to control its width, you can do that too. The tree column can always be identified with `'#0'`. You can use the `column` method to set the width:

```
tree.column('#0', width=50)
```

Comment: I have a couple of other questions:
1. I have 3 columns, which will be name,url,score. should I put them as lines inside the tree in order to insert data under them or I can just insert that data under them by only using headings?
2. I want to control the width of the whole widget,  doing the columsn will affect the whole thing, right?