# Python 3 tkinter treeview, having trouble shifting data from last to first column

Tags: python, tkinter

was trying to figgure out how to display some data from a database in tkinter's
treeview but am hitting a wall on this last bit.
I'm having some trouble with moving data from last column to the first.
Further description within the code comments. 
Hoping anyone out here can point me in the right direction.

```
'''
from tkinter import ttk, Button, Entry, Label, Tk, Scrollbar, Frame

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")

my_frame = Frame(root)
my_frame.pack()

# some value's so interperter doesn't freak out
a = 10
b = 30
c = 50

#  list representing stuff from database query return
list_data = [(a, b, c, 1), (a, b, c, 2), (a, b, c, 3), (a, b, c, 4), 
(a, b, c, 5), (a, b, c, 6), (a, b, c, 7), (a, b, c, 8), (a, b, c, 9), 
(a, b, c, 10), (a, b, c, 11), (a, b, c, 12), (a, c, b, 13), 
(a, b, c, 14),]

#  list to hold column titles
cols = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]


tree = ttk.Treeview(my_frame, selectmode="browse")
tree.pack(side="left")
tree["columns"] = cols
tree["show"] = "headings"

for col in range(len(cols)):
    tree.column(col, width=100, anchor="c")
    tree.heading(col, text=cols[col])

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#  want to shift column 4's data representing rowid to column 1 
#  expected it just to be values=list_data[data-1] but that only shifts 
#  the data vertical inside column 4
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
for data in range(len(list_data)):
    tree.insert("", "end", text=list_data[data], values=list_data[data])


side_scroller = Scrollbar(my_frame, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
side_scroller.pack(side="right", fill="y")

tree.configure(yscrollcommand=side_scroller.set)

root.mainloop()
'''
```

Comment: Do you want: `text=data[-1], values=data[:-1]`

Comment: That gives me an error on the values=data[:-1] if I remove the : it does shift the data but only fills the first column. My idea was just to start reading from the last entry of the tuples and fill all columns with the loop. But thanx for taking a look

Comment: ***gives me an error on the `values=data[:-1]`***: Change to: `for data in list_data:`

Comment: I loose the error that way, but also loose the row of rowid numbers and get a empty last column

Comment: ***loose the row of rowid numbers***: Didn't see anything named `row` or `rowid`? Which value would you show in the first Column, which is set using `text=`?

Comment: I want the int shown last in the tuple to go into column 1 instead of 4.

Comment: I'm making a little database for my electronic components left all the database stuff out to make the code a bit more readable. Just made a list of tuples similair to what the mysqlite returns.

Comment: You didn't display the first Column, disable `# tree["show"] = "headings"` and remove "`col4"` from `cols`. Read [treeview columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49798496/7414759)

Comment: Also wasn't the solution i wanted to do to much in one loop i geuss. I'm gonna try another aproach and shift the data around first before looping it into the treeview thanx for trying helping me out much apriciated.

Comment: Found something that worked posted it as an awnser probably makes it more clear as to what i wanted as output. And most probaly better ways to do it, but am glad you let me figgure it out for myself and not just dropped me the solution still open to see improvements. thanxx again for keeping me trying to get there:)

Answer (score 0):

Been breaking my head on it for some longer found something that works, not pretty but it does the trick feel free to post improvements if you know a better way.
And maybe it will save someone some frustration as a starting point.

```
'''
from tkinter import ttk, Button, Entry, Label, Tk, Scrollbar, Frame

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")

my_frame = Frame(root)
my_frame.pack()

# some value's so interperter doesn't freak out
a = 10
b = 30
c = 50

#  list representing stuff from database query return
list_data = [(a, b, c, 1), (a, b, c, 2), (a, b, c, 3), (a, b, c, 4),
 (a, b, c, 5), (a, b, c, 6), (a, b, c, 7), (a, b, c, 8), (a, b, c, 9),
  (a, b, c, 10), (a, b, c, 11), (a, b, c, 12), (a, c, b, 13),
   (a, b, c, 14),]

#  list to hold column titles
#  changed col1 to row id  and up to 3 for columns to make it more clear
cols = ["row id", "col1", "col2", "col3"]


tree = ttk.Treeview(my_frame, selectmode="browse")
tree.pack(side="left")
tree["columns"] = cols
tree["show"] = "headings"

for col in range(len(cols)):
    tree.column(col, width=100, anchor="c")
    tree.heading(col, text=cols[col])

#  spaghetti code but it does work as intended
#  think the problems came from the list being tuples
#  even after converting to list of lists couldn't shift normally
#  
#  created some lists as placeholders
list1 = []
list_of_lists = []
#  converted list off tuples to list of lists
list_of_lists = [list(elem) for elem in list_data]
#  looping thru the list to change the order to get last entry first
#  did try to do it in a shifting function but couldn't get it to work
for part in list_of_lists:
    list1.append(part[-1])
    list1.append(part[0])
    list1.append(part[1])
    list1.append(part[2])

#  chopped it into pieces still hardcoded length of 4 in for readability of example
chunk = [list1[x:x+4] for x in range(0, len(list1), 4)]

#  back to the original lines but calling chunk instead of list_data
for data in range(len(chunk)):

    tree.insert("", "end", text=chunk[data], values=chunk[data])


side_scroller = Scrollbar(my_frame, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
side_scroller.pack(side="right", fill="y")

tree.configure(yscrollcommand=side_scroller.set)

root.mainloop()
,,,
```